# How can i add items from a listview with a button to another listview at other activity?

Tags: java, android, listview, button, addition

I have programmed a `ListView` at my `MainActivity` with an item view and a Car Class.

```
public class Car {
    private String make;
    private int year;
    private int iconID;
    private String condition;

    public Car(String make, int year, int iconID, String condition) {
        this.make = make;
        this.year = year;
        this.iconID = iconID;
        this.condition = condition;
    }

    public String getMake() {return make;}

    public int getYear() {return year;}

    public int getIconID() {return iconID;}

    public String getCondition() {return condition;}


}
```

My **MainActivity** Class looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    ActionBar actionBar;

    private List<Car> myCars = new ArrayList<Car>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter();

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar1);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();  

        populateCarList();
        populateListView();

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }   

    private void populateCarList() {
        myCars.add(new Car("Ford", 1940, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Needing work"));
        myCars.add(new Car("Benz", 1960, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Cheap"));
        myCars.add(new Car("Mustang", 2000, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Needing new owner"));
        myCars.add(new Car("BMW", 2012, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Needing a lot of work!"));
        myCars.add(new Car("Toyota", 1940, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Oldtimer"));
        myCars.add(new Car("VW", 2003, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Cool"));
        myCars.add(new Car("Ferrari", 2008, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Nice"));

    }

    private void populateListView() {
        ArrayAdapter<Car> adapter = new MyListAdapter();
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.carsListView);

        TextView textView = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
        textView.setText("Here you can see all the Cars!");
        textView.setTextSize(15);
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#a60b0b"));
        list.addHeaderView(textView);

        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    private  class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Car> {
        public MyListAdapter() {
            super(MainActivity.this, R.layout.item_view, myCars);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View itemView = convertView;
            if(itemView == null){
                itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false);
            }

            String url;
            switch(position){
                case 0: url = "http://www.google.com"; break;
                case 1: url = "http://www.google.com"; break;
                case 2: url = "http://www.google.com"; break;
                case 3: url = "http://www.google.com"; break;
                case 4: url = "http://www.google.com"; break;
                case 5: url = "http://www.google.com"; break;
                case 6: url = "http://www.google.com"; break;
                default: url = "http://www.google.com"; break;
            }
            Button button = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_button);
            button.setTag(url);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String url = (String)v.getTag();

                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                }
            });

            Car currentCar = myCars.get(position);


            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_icon);
            imageView.setImageResource(currentCar.getIconID());

            // Make:
            TextView makeText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_txtMake);
            makeText.setText(currentCar.getMake());

            // Year:
            TextView yearText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_txtYear);
            yearText.setText("" + currentCar.getYear());

            // Condition:
            TextView conditionText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_txtCondition);
            conditionText.setText(currentCar.getCondition());


            return itemView;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        if (id == android.R.id.home){
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        }

        if (id == R.id.watchList) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, WatchListActivity.class));
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void addCarToWatchList (View view){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Car has been added to WatchList", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } 
}
```

And I also have a `WatchList` Class (or a `FavoriteCarsList` Class whatever you want to call it)

```
public class WatchListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_watch_list);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        if (id == android.R.id.home){
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        }

        if (id == R.id.watchList) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, WatchListActivity.class));
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

The xml code for the item view looks like:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/item_icon"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Make shown here"
    android:id="@+id/item_txtMake"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="2000"
    android:id="@+id/item_txtYear"
    android:layout_below="@+id/item_icon"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Condition shown Here"
    android:id="@+id/item_txtCondition"
    android:layout_below="@+id/item_txtYear"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Buy Car online!"
    android:id="@+id/item_button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/item_txtCondition"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="add Car to WatchList"
    android:onClick="addCarToWatchList"
    android:id="@+id/item_watchlist_button"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/item_icon"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_button"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/item_button" />
```

(At first: don't get confused by the www.google.com links for the buttons or the same image (ic_launcher) for every car, I used it only for testing my code. The Button is there, to get to an Link where you can buy the Car for example.)

So everything is OK. I can run the app without an error. All Buttons  working. I get a `ListView` at my `MainActivity` with the different Cars and at the `ToolBar` I have an Icon, which I can click and switch to the `WatchList` Activity. Everything is exactly as I want it.

But I can't find a solution for my next step.

First: I want to add another Button to my `item_view.xml`. It has to be like an "Add to WatchList"-Button. If I click that Button, the car-item has to be added to the `ListView` of the `WatchList` Activity. (the `ListView` at the `WatchList` Class doesn't exist yet)

Second: If an item is added to the `WatchList`, it has to be an own Layout (own `item_watchlist_view.xml`) which only includes (for example) the name and the image of the item_view.xml from the `MainActivity`. It would be also nice, if there is a delete-Button at the `item_watchlist_view.xml`, which could be used for deleting the Car from the `WatchList` if I don't want it anymore in my `WatchList`.

So basically the app have to run like a "shopping cart system" but the difference is that I have only cars as products and I can add them to a `WatchList` or `FavoriteList` ("Shopping cart").

I tried a lot of things for two weeks but nothing works... so I decided to sign up here at the community with hope for help.

It would be nice, if someone can give me an detailed answer!

Thank you.. and sorry for my bad English!

Comment: Generally, you should make a class `WatchList`, include a list in that class, and pass that class to your second activity. Then use an adapter to access the information in the class `WatchList` to populate the ListView in your second activity.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I saw a similar solution at a forum before but i can't solve my problem with this answer.

Comment: What's your problem with that solution?

Comment: For example: How can i pass that WatchList class to another second activity ?

Comment: You have different options for that. One would be to store that `WatchList` and its Entries in a Database, like SQLite, and just pass the ID of the wanted List as an Integer to the Bundle, and then load the List in the new Activity. Or you could make `WatchList` implement `Parcelable` and add all methods needed, and then pass the `WatchList` directly in the `Intent`. I'll put an answer to show you how to pass paramaters via Intent.

Answer (score 1):

To pass parameters to a new Activity, call it by invoking

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, WatchListActivity.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putInt("key", 1); //Your id
intent.putExtras(b); //Put your id to your next Intent
startActivity(intent);
```